# Etymology of 'ripped' as in 'ripped abs'

Tags: etymology, slang

ODO provides the following definition for the word [ripped](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ripped):

> 3. *informal* having well-defined or well-developed muscles; muscular:
>   *through his slightly-too-tight shirt you could see **he was ripped***
>   *they’re going to the gym daily to get buff pecs, **ripped abs**, and tight buns*

How did this sense of the word come about?

Comment: Interesting that OED gives a similar definition of *ripped* but no etymology other than *rip vi + -ed*, and *rip* doesn't mention a sense where there could be a meaning of *ripped* = "built"

Answer (score 5):

The very earliest citation given by the *OED* is

> 1974   C. Gaines *Pumping Iron* ix. 172   There was Leon Brown with his perfectly chiseled, wasp-waisted build, and his quiet polished routine; and Bob Birdsong,..looking very ripped and close to the skin.

Which unfortunately doesn't give any help as to the etymology.

The 1981 edition of the book makes it clear that *ripped* originally referred to the "clarity" (definition) of the muscles, not to their size:

> 1981   C. Gaines *Pumping Iron* 230   … everybody else, it seems, has got muscularity—which is a combination of both size and clarity of the muscles. Everybody is both big *and* ripped …

My guess is that *ripped* refers to the way that the muscles and veins of bodybuilders with very little subcutaneous fat appear to "rip" through their skin ([as seen on this gentleman](http://i.b5z.net/i/u/230085/i/NPCCollegiateNationalsMostMuscularOutdoorzoom_ezr.jpg)).

Comment: I agree. "Ripped" is a higher level of "Cut". It's the definition being emphasized. +1 for OED citation where the quote defines *ripped* by adding *and close to the skin*.

Answer (score 4):

*Ripped* may be a variation of of *rippled*, but there are a number of other synonyms that also suggest something *cut*, for example from *[Talk the Talk: The Slang of 65 American Subcultures](http://books.google.fi/books?id=dG0hRbvV2yEC&pg=PA46&dq=ripped%20muscles%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FFX5UMXUOsLm4QSoiYC4DA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ripped%20&f=false)* (Luc Reid - 2011):

> *buffed, buff, cut, defined, shredded, sliced, sliced and diced*

It looks like *ripped* came from an extension of *cut*, itself an extension of *defined* and *moulded* by way of having all that is extraneous removed, leaving just muscle. Other terms such as *chiseled*, *razor sharp*, *shredded*, *sliced* and *lacerated* follow the same pattern.

The Oxford English Dictionary has *ripped* from 1974 with an origin in bodybuilding. They say it's also used as *ripped up*.

*Ripped up* mirrors *cut up*, that came from *cuts*, *cut*, and *clear cut*, referring to the sharp angular shape of built-up muscles. These uses of *cut* goes back to at least 1940, all within the bodybuilding community.

---

Here's an early January 1976 use of two of the terms together ([*Muscle Builder*, Vol 17, Num 1, Page 43, January 1976](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?mb760143)), and interesting to see *cut-up*, which shows similarity to the early *ripped-up*:

> John Isaacs, 45 years young, was unbelievable **ripped** - more **cut-up** than a Christmas goose - and he gave the youngsters a lesson in muscularity by winning the coveted "Most Muscular Man" award.

And the next paragraph shows *cut* used as a noun rather than adjective:

> Among the also-rans, Dave Mastorakis was massive but lacked the former **cuts** he displayed last year.

More *cut* elsewhere:

> - Paul, the giant 225-pound block of granite from Wales, was sensationally thick and **cut to ribbons**.
> - **Sharp cuts**, posing and symmetry gave him a surprise 2nd in the Tall Class.
> - Joe Nista, 46, returns from retirement with all his former density and **cuts**.

---

If we trace the history of *cut*, we can see how it was used to describe *sharp* muscles, and how it spawned other similar adjectives and nouns.

This 1974 description of Mr. Universe winner Louie Ferrigno describes exactly what *cut* meant ([*Muscle Builder*, Vol 15, Num 3, Page 24, July 1974](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?mb740724)):

> Ferrigno needn't have posed, needn't have twicthed a single muscle fibre, or lifted a toe. Just to see him inert was to believe the unbelievable. The biggest superstar ever, and all of him **cut to shreds; lacerated, the skin beaten and hacked away** so that only sinews and tendons and veins and striations and unbespeakable musclemusclemuscle remained. . .

---

The following shows why the adjective *cut* was used, and how it changed into a noun.

*IronMan*, Vol 23, No 6, Page 11, [September 1964](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?im230611):

> Randy [Watson, Jr. Mr. America] has maintained his superb definition or "cuts" as the fellows now prefer to call it.

*IronMan*, Vol 18, No 2, Page 9, [September 1958](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?im18029):

> Tom [Sansone, "Mr. America 1958"]'s 14½ inch forearm is cut into planes when flexed, rounded and full when relaxed.

*Strength & Health*, Page 26, [November 1952](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?sh521126):

> [George] Paine wins "best legs" and it's easy to see why. He has the **deepest "cuts"** I've ever seen in his thighs. They look like they've been **chiseled** out of marble.

*Strength & Health*, Page 23, [July 1940](http://www.musclememory.com/showArticle.php?sh400723):

> "Chick" Deutsch, won the Best Abdominals and it was quite an easy victory for him. Seldom have I seen such fine **clear cut** straight abdominals and external **obliques** as this young favorite ad popular athlete possesses.

Answer (score 2):

Like most slang, sometimes it's hard to pin down the exact origin of the phrase. I'm sure it was used in bodybuilding circles before the 70s, but I couldn't find any citations earlier than that.

My feeling is the term was popularized in the general public by the book [**Ripped: The Sensible Way to Achieve Ultimate Muscularity**](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Ripped.html?id=9KOWpwAACAAJ) which was published in 1980.

An [interview with a Gay Games competitor](http://books.google.ca/books?id=c5MCAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22ripped%22%20bodybuilding&hl=en&sa=X&ei=64n4UJvzLpKsqQHEoYG4Bw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ripped%22%20bodybuilding&f=false) in the June 20, 1994 edition of New York magazine had this comment on bodybuilder Jargon:

> **Bodybuilding Jargon:** “*Cut* means you have sufficient definition; *ripped* is a higher order of cut. If you’re *shattered*, you are without any fat whatsoever. By the games, I will be ripped.”

So while there may be some coincidental relation to the tearing and rebuilding of muscles to build them up, I believe the jargon was developed from the previous metaphor of muscles being “cut” — as if the bodybuilder was chiseled from stone by Michelangelo.

Answer (score 1):

In Arnold Schwarzenegger's 1978 *[Arnold: The Education of a Bodybuilder](http://books.google.com/books?ei=Rcf4UNipOZLM9gTjt4HQDw&sqi=2&id=MQbripC1OtQC&dq=%22ripped%20*%20poses%22&q=ripped#search_anchor)*, there's a description of bodybuilder Chet Yorton's stage style that uses the verb *rip* to describe the act of bodybuilder posing. Is it possible that this was common bodybuilding jargon at the time? I can't find any proof of it, but thought it was worth mentioning.

[image: http://books.google.com/books?ei=Rcf4UNipOZLM9gTjt4HQDw&sqi=2&id=MQbripC1OtQC&dq=%22ripped+*+poses%22&q=ripped#search_anchor]

Comment: Interesting, since in Schwarzenegger's native German,  "rib" is "rippe".

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this use of ripped is in the sense of torn. Muscle growth I believe comes about due to damaged or torn muscle fibre.

Comment: While we are speculating....there was a period during the 80's when torn (actually vertically slashed) shirts were popular attire among bodybuilders. I started hearing the word after that, so perhaps the word initially refered to the "ripped" shirts?

Comment: My speculation is similar to @T.E.D.'s - but it goes back a bit further. When those torn shirts were in style, I always thought they were meant to look like [the Incredible Hulk](http://hughescoloring.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/hulk.jpg?w=627&h=418) in the middle of his transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if it weren't somehow introduced by Arnold Schwarzenegger as to shred is schredden in German.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Your answer offers an interesting comparison to German. You could improve your answer with some citation to a source, and by explaining the link between Schwarzenegger and muscles.